# trouble installing phonegap

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, phonegap-build

I ran `sudo npm install -g phonegap` and it seemed to install but when I try to call `phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld` I got `zsh: command not found: phonegap`

The only problem seemed to be this line: `npm WARN engine ncallbacks@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.6.7"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.13","npm":"1.3.2"})`

Any idea what to do here?

Comment: what tells you a "which phonegap" on the commandline? possibly phonegap is not in your PATH. it's normally located at /usr/local/bin ...

Comment: might automatically install into path once you restart terminal and/or computer.